# Need help in choosing between xsl:for-each and xsl:template

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an xml from one format to another and i need some help as i am new to xslt.
My input/source xml is like this:

```
<field id="1" media="video" name="ContentLayout" value="Refer to Content Layout View">
        <specifiedLayout />
        <actualLayout>
          <segment endsmptetimecode="00:00:01:03" endtimecode="00:00:01:126" startsmptetimecode="00:00:00:00" starttimecode="00:00:00:000" type="Black" />        
          <segment endsmptetimecode="00:03:23:03" endtimecode="00:03:23:120" startsmptetimecode="00:00:01:03" starttimecode="00:00:01:126" type="Content" />
        Goes on...
        </actualLayout>
</field>
```

And the desired output xml should be like this:

```
<field id="1" media="video" name="ContentLayout" value="Refer to Content Layout View">
        <specifiedLayout/>
        <actualLayout>
          <segment end="00:00:02:002" endSMPTE="00:00:02:00" start="00:00:00:000" startSMPTE="00:00:00:00" type="Black"/>
          <segment end="00:00:47:081" endSMPTE="00:00:47:02" start="00:00:02:002" startSMPTE="00:00:02:00" type="Content"/>
        </actualLayout>
</field>
```

And the mapping of the attributes is like this:

```
start = starttimecode
end = endtimecode
startSMPTE = startsmptetimecode
endSMPTE = endsmptetimecode
type = type
```

I am able to identify the xml node like this:

```
<xsl:when test="@name='ContentLayout'">
```

I am thinking of using a `xsl:for-each`, and inside the loop declare 5 variables to store the attribute values, and then reassign it.

I some how feel its not right approach to do it. I dont know how can i use `xsl:template` in this type of scenario.
Can anyone help me / advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a case like this, where you need to keep most of the existing structure and only make a few changes, it is convenient to start with the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) template as the rule, and add a few templates as exceptions to the rule:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@starttimecode">
    <xsl:attribute name="start">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@endtimecode">
    <xsl:attribute name="end">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@startsmptetimecode">
    <xsl:attribute name="startSMPTE">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@endsmptetimecode">
    <xsl:attribute name="endSMPTE">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I am getting warning as : xsl:template cannot be a child of xsl:when.
Below is my code segment:

        `<xsl:when test="@name='ContentLayout'">
                    <!-- identity transform -->
                    <xsl:template match="ContentLayout">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:template>
                  </xsl:when>`

Comment: @Santosh-Sidd Why doesn't my stylesheet work for you as is?

Comment: I am getting warning as : xsl:template cannot be a child of xsl:when. 

Below is my code segment: 
<xsl:when test="@name='ContentLayout'"> <!-- identity transform --> <xsl:template match="ContentLayout"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template> </xsl:when>

Comment: Please let's not go in a circle.

Comment: @ michael.hor257k - I am using a xsl:when condition and i cannot place xsl:template inside it.

Comment: "*I am using a xsl:when condition*" Yes, I understand that. But I don't understand why. I don't see anything in your question that would require it. I suggest you try my stylesheet **without any modifications** and if it doesn't provide the expected output, then explain where it fails.

Comment: This demonstrates that providing working code to solve a user's problem is not always the best way of answering the question, if they don't have the basic concepts needed to understand the code. I don't have the time to write an essay on the concepts of template rules, so I would just suggest that @Santosh-Sidd that s/he needs to do more reading on the basics of the language. There are plenty of good books and tutorials available.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I am using a when condition because the source XML is big and contains many fields, and this is just one part of the xml where i am finding it difficult.

Comment: @Santosh-Sidd That's not a reason to use `xsl:when`. And, as you have found out, templates need to be at the top level of the stylesheet. If you have other tasks for the stylesheet to perform, you need to add more templates. I am afraid I cannot help you further with this - certainly not within comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use local-name() to get the value of element/attribute.
 ex :

you try below code

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template     match="@starttimecode|@endtimecode|@startsmptetimecode|@endsmptetimecode|@type">
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'starttimecode'">
  <xsl:attribute name="start">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="local-name() = 'endtimecode'">
  <xsl:attribute name="end">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="local-name() = 'startsmptetimecode'">
  <xsl:attribute name="startSMPTE">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="local-name() = 'endsmptetimecode'">
  <xsl:attribute name="endSMPTE">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="local-name() = 'type'">
  <xsl:attribute name="type">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```