# Using a variable outside the scope of XSLT template

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform an xml from one format to another and i need some help as i am new to xslt. My input/source xml is like this:

```
<field name="Duration">
    <Duration value="00:13:56:544" />
    <DurationFrames value="20057" />
    <DurationSMPTE value="00:13:56:13" />
</field>
```

And the desired output xml should be like this:

```
<field internal="yes" name="Frames" value="20057"/>
<field internal="yes" name="Duration_msec" value="00:13:56:544"/>
<field internal="yes" name="Duration_SMPTE" value="00:13:56:13"/>
<field name="Duration" value="00:13:56:544(13)"/>
```

Here the value of Duration:00:13:56:544(13) is a combination of two fields:

1) Duration_msec (00:13:56:544)

2) The last part of Duration_SMPTE (00:13:56:13) which is 13

This is a small segment of a larger XML, i am only posting the XML node where i am finding difficulty.

Here is what the XSLT i have written:

```
<xsl:when test="@name='Duration'">                    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
 </xsl:when>
```

and here are my templates:

```
  <xsl:template match="Duration">
    <xsl:variable name="var_Duration_val" select="@value" />
    <field internal="yes" name="Duration_msec" value="{$var_Duration_val}"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DurationFrames">
    <xsl:variable name="var_Duration_Frames" select="@value" />
    <field internal="yes" name="Frames" value="{$var_Duration_Frames}"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="DurationSMPTE">
    <xsl:variable name="var_Duration_smpte" select="@value" />
    <field internal="yes" name="Duration_SMPTE" value="{$var_Duration_smpte}"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

I am facing problem in achieving the last part , ie,

```
<field name="Duration" value="00:13:56:544(13)"/>
```

The variables are in scope of different templates. Please help me in achieving the last line of output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply:

```
<xsl:template match="field[@name='Duration']">
    <field internal="yes" name="Frames" value="{DurationFrames/@value}"/>
    <field internal="yes" name="Duration_msec" value="{Duration/@value}"/>
    <field internal="yes" name="Duration_SMPTE" value="{DurationSMPTE/@value}"/>
    <field name="Duration" value="{Duration/@value}({substring(DurationSMPTE/@value, 10,2)})"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The xsl:template match="field[@name='Duration']" didnt work/match the xml node. But the other lines helped me.

Comment: Here is what worked for me :
    `<xsl:when test="@name='Duration'">                                          
                    <field internal="yes" name="Frames" value="{DurationFrames/@value}"/>
                    <field internal="yes" name="Duration_msec" value="{Duration/@value}"/>
                    <field internal="yes" name="Duration_SMPTE" value="{DurationSMPTE/@value}"/>
                    <field name="Duration" value="{Duration/@value}({substring(DurationSMPTE/@value, 10,2)})"/>
                  </xsl:when>`

Comment: I don't see your entire stylesheet, but same as in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35860500/need-help-in-choosing-between-xslfor-each-and-xsltemplate) I suspect you are using `xsl:choose` where you *should* be using individual templates.

Comment: Thank you very much :) you are gud :)